# Is Android with KNOX secure?

Tags: encryption, android

I'm thinking about the creation of a application that has a high security requirement.
The main functionality is storing text and image data that it gets from a server.

The device will only be used for this specific App.
To get a start on securing the device i will ofcourse do the android device encryption and i can use Samsung Knox SDK's and Container to do the following:

- attestation
- whitelist only required applications
- disable connectios except GPRS
- create Knox container with my App inside

The application will store all data in a SQLCipher database (https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)
Anything being stored in the DB will first be AES 256 encrypted
The server will use a self signed SSL certificate will be distributed with the application.

Im wondering how secure would this be?
I know that getting passed the device login and encryption won't be a problem but how about the Knox login?
What about the possibility of getting remote access to the device and just wait till user enters his Knox password and inside the Knox container his encryption password?

Update:

Questions:

Will this be enough to prevent attackers from gaining access to the data?

Is it still possible to get remote access to the device (without having physical access) to wait and record credentials when entered?

If yes how about the Knox container password and encryption password inside Knox container?

Is the Knox container something i can trust?